# Is there any live tracker following the adverse events for COVID-19 vaccines?

Tags: covid-19, statistics, covid-19-datasets

I have seen a few trackers for the vaccination campaign:

1. https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/covid-vaccine-tracker-global-distribution/
2. https://ourworldindata.org/covid-vaccinations
3. https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/world/covid-vaccinations-tracker.html

Is there any live tracker following the adverse events for  COVID-19 vaccines?

Answer (score 1):

[Liam Goldstein](https://www.quora.com/profile/Liam-Goldstein-5) [pointed](https://qr.ae/pGXARc) me to the [Vaccine Adverse Event Reporting System (VAERS)](https://vaers.hhs.gov/) in the United States.

https://vaers.hhs.gov/faq.html#collapse17:

> Healthcare providers [in the United States] are required to report to VAERS the following adverse events after COVID-19 vaccination [under Emergency Use Authorization (EUA)], and other adverse events if later revised by CDC:

The VAERS makes their data available for download at https://vaers.hhs.gov/data.html.

https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/vaccines/safety/adverse-events.html:

> Over **109 million doses of COVID-19 vaccines were administered in the United States** from December 14, 2020, through March 15, 2021. During this time, **VAERS received 1,913 reports of death (0.0018%) among people who received a COVID-19 vaccine**. CDC and FDA physicians review each case report of death as soon as notified and CDC requests medical records to further assess reports. A review of available clinical information including death certificates, autopsy, and medical records revealed **no evidence that vaccination contributed to patient deaths**. CDC and FDA will continue to investigate reports of adverse events, including deaths, reported to VAERS.

Note, from https://www.dw.com/en/fact-check-no-links-found-between-vaccination-and-deaths/a-56458746

> As far back as 2015, [a study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4599698/) assessing claims of deaths from vaccinations highlights that data from the VAERS system is skewed, as it is a system which "accepts any submitted report of an adverse event without judging its clinical significance or whether it was caused by a vaccination." The [Centers for Disease Control and Prevention](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/acip/meetings/downloads/slides-2021-01/06-COVID-Shimabukuro.pdf) also warns against reporting bias and inconsistent data quality in the VAERS system.